# How to create a log folder on cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I am new to RoR. I am using capistrano to deploy an RoR app.

I would like to create a log folder in `current/public/log` on each deploy. I am currently creating this folder manually and grating permissions to it. Is there a way I can do this everytime I do a deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your deploy task:

```
execute "mkdir -p current/public/log; chmod u+rwx current/public/log"
```

Comment: joews : I found that I can create a task and use `after "deploy"`. Should I define the task inside `namespace :deploy` or can I define it anywhere in the deploy.rb??